# Why i get CAMERA_ERROR (3) when using flutter camera

Tags: flutter, camera

the following error occurs when using flutter camera plugin, I've added the permission to the manifest file, and still not working.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:64116/dm5AqTZrDK0=/ws
I/CameraManagerGlobal(20232): Connecting to camera service
W/Gralloc4(20232): allocator 3.x is not supported
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232): Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating:
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232): android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2231)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1241)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:578)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.closeCaptureSession(Camera.java:480)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.close(Camera.java:486)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera$2.onError(Camera.java:187)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.notifyError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1629)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.lambda$oDs27OTfKFfK18rUW2nQxxkPdV0(Unknown Source:0)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.-$$Lambda$CameraDeviceImpl$oDs27OTfKFfK18rUW2nQxxkPdV0.accept(Unknown Source:8)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:278)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:201)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/CameraCaptureSession(20232):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/flutter (20232): CameraException(Previous capture has not returned yet., takePicture was called before the previous capture returned.)
```

Comment: The problem seems pretty clear here:
I/flutter (20232): CameraException(Previous capture has not returned yet., takePicture was called before the previous capture returned.)

Maybe you could enlighten us with some code to help you understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also now use this plugin : [CamerAwesome](https://github.com/Apparence-io/camera_awesome)

Official plugin has been quite abandonned. This plugin includes flash, zoom, auto focus... and no initialisation required.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error when using Flutter [camera plugin example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/camera/example/lib/main.dart) when I changed it from `CameraController.startVideoRecording()` to `CameraController.startImageStream(Function<CameraImage>)`.

To resolve this issue I commented/removed `imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg` at CameraController instantiation:

```
controller = CameraController(
  cameraDescription,
  ResolutionPreset.medium,
  enableAudio: enableAudio,
  //imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg, //remove or comment this line
);
```

This may happen because `CameraImage` received at `startImageStream` [uses YUV image encoding](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348).